# Why I get permission denied in Dev-C++?

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, compilation, dev-c++

I have a proyect with the main class and 2 classes that i want to link into the main one. When I try to compile it, a message appears which says: "can't create main.o: Permission denied". "Recipe for target 'main.o' failed". I am trying to compile it in Windows with Dev-C++. Any suggest on what can cause that error? I have try it on another computer and it worked perfectly, so i guess that the problema is not in the code.

Comment: Where are you trying to compile your code? Do you have permission to write to that directory?

Comment: No, I have the proyect in a folder on my desktop, without permissions